# Use Angular inside Neutralinojs

Tags: angular, neutralinojs

Neutralinojs binary version used : v4.10.0
Neutralinojs client version used : v3.8.2
Angular version used : v15.0.0

Question : How to use Angular as frontend framework with Neutralinojs?

Answer (score 3):

Note: I'm making this because the documentation for NeutralinoJS is currently incomplete, and also because I don't want to forget.

Before we start, there're several things in this answer that assumes you to know how:

- How to setup a new Angular project
- Hot to setup a new Neutralinojs project

### Setup

1. Create an empty folder, in order to make things tidy
2. Open a terminal and direct it to the empty folder you just made at step 1
3. Create both an Angular project and a NeutralinoJS project inside the empty folder. For demonstration purposes, let's name the Angular project `"frontend"` and the NeutralinoJS project `"backend"`

```
ng new frontend
neu create backend
```

4. Open another terminal so that you have two terminals open. Navigate each terminal to the respective folders created using the `ng new` and `neu create` commands.
5. In the Angular project, you need to declare `window.Neutralino`. To do this, you'll need the type definitions file. Install `@neutralinojs/lib` as a `devDependency` in your Angular project

```
npm i -D @neutralinojs/lib
```

6. In your Angular project's `main.ts` file (or any other `*.component.ts` file, as long as this code runs before you use the NeutralinoJS API), add the following code:

```js
import * as neutralinojs from "@neutralinojs/lib";

declare global{
  const Neutralino: typeof neutralinojs;
}

Neutralino.init();
```

7. Locate `neutralino.js` file and move it to the `assets` folder inside your Angular project from either:

- `/node_modules/@neutralinojs/lib/dist/neutralino.js` inside your Angular project folder
  OR
- From `/resources/js/neutralino.js` inside your Neutralinojs project folder

8. After placing `neutralino.js` file to your Angular project's `assets` folder, now call it from `index.html` on your Angular project by adding:

```html
<script src="assets/neutralino.js"></script>
```

9. Now, Open the `angular.json` file located in the root folder of your Angular project and modify the following property:

```
"projects": {
 "frontend": {
  "architect": {
   "build": {
    "options": {
     "outputPath": "../backend/resources/",
```

10. Lastly, in your NeutralinoJS project folder, open the `neutralino.config.json` file and modify the following property:

```js
// ...
  "cli": {
    "clientLibrary": "/resources/assets/neutralino.js",
// ...
```

And we're set.

### Development / Production

1. In the terminal where your Angular project is running, run the following command:

```
npm run watch
```

or the equivalent `ng` command:

```
ng build --watch --configuration development
```

*Note: This command will remove the `resources` folder inside your NeutralinoJS folder (or the specified folder path from step 9 in the setup process).

Once the command from step 1 has finished compiling and is waiting for changes:

2a.  run the following command in the terminal where your NeutralinoJS project is located:

```
neu run
```

2b. For production, run the following command in the terminal where your NeutralinoJS project is located:

```
neu build
```

*Note: Make sure to use a different terminal from the one used in step 1, as both processes need to run simultaneously.

Now you have NeutralinoJS working together with Angular and change detection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did setup a → **[git repo](https://github.com/zeuros/neutralino-angular)** ← to get started with Neutralino+Angular using your tutorial

Answer (score 0):

just go to this page,

https://neutralino.js.org/docs/getting-started/using-frontend-libraries

read the page carefully and do step by step, at the End
it occures an Error:
neutralino-win_x64.exe was stopped with error code ...

download this file

https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/releases/download/v4.14.0/neutralinojs-v4.14.0.zip

and replace it to the bin folder,
it'll work,
if you needed any help you can message me,
good luck